# Golang não deveria ser sinônimo de Go? Ou vice-versa?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tag-específica

A tag [golang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) não deveria ser sinônimo de [go](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)?

Pelo que eu sei sobre Go, ambas as tags significam o mesmo. Além do mais a abreviação de [GoLang](https://golang.org/) é usada para se referir a Go:

> The **Go** Programming **Lang**uage

E também no wiki de tag da tag [golang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) está dito isso:

> ...Go (**também conhecida como GoLang**) é uma linguagem de programação...

Então, a tag [golang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) não deveria ser sinônimo de [go](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)? Ou vice-versa?

---

Acredito que tenha sido criado a tag [golang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) primeiramente, mas acredito que se deve manter [golang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) como sinônimo de [go](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) assim como no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go).

Perguntei também devido ao uso das *tag*s desta questão: [Quais são as principais características da linguagem Go?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227429/66203)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Está feito!

---

Comment: Que rápido! Obrigado. Mas não seria o melhor o contrário, [tag:golang] ser sinônimo de [tag:go]?

Comment: Isto dá pra debater, mas dificulta a busca ter só 2 letras, se alguém mostrar que é melhor, é só inverter.

Comment: De qualquer maneira, obrigado! Esse pode ser um assunto para um debate posterior mesmo. Pode ficar para depois, afinal hoje é sexta-feira =).

Comment: @Stormwind eu acho mais bonito [tag:golang], evita entrar em conflito com linguagens e ferramentas onde `go` é uma palavra chave. Por curiosidade, fui ver no internacional, lá está [tag:go]